# How to set a local proxy for redirecting traffic to remote proxies?

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, proxy, tcp

I use proxies (with authentication) in various applications (not system proxy). Thus, I have to update all proxy settings when the proxies or the credentials are changed.

I wish to set a fixed local proxy (e.g., 127.0.0.1:555) to use it in all applications and then redirect all the traffic to the current choice of proxy.

Could you please give me a hint about where to start?

Comment: Where you able to set up the proxy for this? How is it configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install and configure a proxy server locally.  Whatever you choose to install must, itself, support being configured to use a proxy server.

I would start with [tinyproxy](https://tinyproxy.github.io/) (see Ubuntu [package tinyproxy](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tinyproxy) ).

It looks like this supports rules for setting some domains via an "upstream".  [See the documentation](https://tinyproxy.github.io/#documentation):

> - Upstream, No Upstream
>
>   This option allows you to set up a set of rules
>     for deciding whether an upstream proxy server is to be used, based on
>     the host or domain of the site being accessed. The rules are stored in
>     the order encountered in the configuration file and the LAST matching
>     rule wins. There are three possible forms for specifying upstream
>     rules:
>
>   - upstream host:port turns proxy upstream support on generally.
>   - upstream host:port "site_spec" turns on the upstream proxy for the
>       sites matching site_spec.
>   - no upstream "site_spec" turns off upstream
>       support for sites matching site_spec.

The first rule type sends everything via another proxy.