# Google chrome connect directly to Internet even when opened with proxy

Tags: debian, chrome, proxy, parrotsec

I'm using ParrotSec (Debian based) and installed Google Chrome recently. Unlike Firefox, Google Chrome doesn't have an option to set a proxy in the UI instead it uses system proxy. In my case, I wanted it to work with Burp Suite and need Chrome traffic to go through the proxy http://127.0.0.1:8080.

I tried the following commands on terminal. Each one opens Chrome, but the proxy doesn't work. Chrome is directly connecting to internet.

```
google-chrome --proxy-server="https://127.0.0.1:8080"
google-chrome --proxy-server="https=127.0.0.1:8080"
google-chrome --proxy-server="http://127.0.0.1:8080"
google-chrome --proxy-server="http=127.0.0.1:8080"
```

None of them worked. Proxy is working perfectly in Firefox, but not in Chrome. Any idea what's happening?

Additional info: I'm using the OVA downloaded from ParrotSec in Virtual Box and the desktop environment is *mate 1.24.0*. I verified the --proxy-server flag exist by `typing man google-chrome-stable`

Comment: I really doubt this would be the issue, but just for the sake of completeness can you also try `google-chrome --proxy-server="127.0.0.1:8080"`?

Comment: I already tried it without the quotes. Will try with the quotes now. Update: not working. It's still connecting to internet directly.

Comment: You want to run google chrome with a different proxy to the rest of your system because you want one site to be passed through a proxy and not others.  Is that correct?

Comment: Hi @PhilipCouling kinda yes. I don't use any systemwide proxy. I need Google chrome to use a proxy by burp suite so that I can do my pentest tasks.

Comment: The question is a bit different but I wonder if this answer might help you? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/577859/20140 It would be possible to set up a system wide local which automatically forwards to another proxy for some sites and not others.

Comment: It is unlikely to be of much help, but you may add your Chrome version and the steps you took to conclude that Chrome's traffic is not flowing through the proxy.

Comment: @fra-san the Chrome version is 85.0.4183.102 x64. Burp Suite have an option called interceptor, which intercept and hold the request if turned on and we've to manually forward each request. Also there's another tab called http history. That's how I verified it.

Comment: Does `http_proxy=https://127.0.0.1:8080 google-chrome` work any better?

Comment: @roaima I tried it but it doesn't work. Chrome directly connects to internet.

Comment: I've grown so tired of this that for years now I have been using a script which sets **all 4** variables (`http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, `HTTP_PROXY`, and `HTTPS_PROXY`) then runs the given command.  Also, with ref to @roaima's answer, the *value* of the env var typically is `http` not `https`.  So basically in your case, try `https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8080` and then `HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8080`

Comment: @sitaram thanks for the correction

Comment: Not a fix, but to ensure that chrome can not get around the proxy, set up `nftables` to block this user from accessing the network. If you need finer grain control then use app-armour.